# Couldn't connect to IBMQ server

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

When I access IBM Q backend with qiskit code, an error occurs.

```
from qiskit import IBMQ 

qt = 'xxxxxxxxx'

IBMQ.save_account(qt)
IBMQ.load_accounts()
```

The error message is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/utils.py in obtain_token(self, config)
    135             response.raise_for_status()
--> 136             self.data_credentials = response.json()
    137         except (requests.HTTPError, ValueError) as ex:

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    896                     pass
--> 897         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    898 

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ApiError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqsingleprovider.py in _authenticate(cls, credentials)
     94 
---> 95     def _discover_remote_backends(self):
     96         """Return the remote backends available.

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/ibmqconnector.py in __init__(self, token, config, verify)
    103         self.req = Request(token, config=config, verify=verify)
--> 104 
    105     def _check_backend(self, backend_name):

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/utils.py in __init__(self, token, config, verify, retries, timeout_interval)
    216                                       proxy_urls=self.proxy_urls,
--> 217                                       ntlm_credentials=self.ntlm_credentials)
    218 

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/utils.py in __init__(self, token, config, verify, proxy_urls, ntlm_credentials)
     67         if token:
---> 68             self.obtain_token(config=self.config)
     69         else:

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/utils.py in obtain_token(self, config)
    137         except (requests.HTTPError, ValueError) as ex:
--> 138             raise ApiError('error during login: %s' % str(ex))
    139 

ApiError: error during login: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-2e30fdf423aa> in <module>
     11 IBMQ.stored_accounts()
     12 
---> 13 IBMQ.load_accounts()
     14 #IBMQ.enable_account(qt)

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqprovider.py in load_accounts(self, **kwargs)
    197 
    198     def disable_accounts(self, **kwargs):
--> 199         """Disable accounts in the current session, subject to optional filtering.
    200 
    201         The filter kwargs can be `token`, `url`, `hub`, `group`, `project`.

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqprovider.py in _append_account(self, credentials)
    277         """
    278         return all(getattr(credentials, key_, None) == value_ for
--> 279                    key_, value_ in filter_dict.items())

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqsingleprovider.py in __init__(self, credentials, ibmq_provider)
     50         self.credentials = credentials
     51         self._api = self._authenticate(self.credentials)
---> 52         self._ibm_provider = ibmq_provider
     53 
     54         # Populate the list of remote backends.

/usr/local/oss/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqsingleprovider.py in _authenticate(cls, credentials)
    101         """
    102         ret = OrderedDict()
--> 103         configs_list = self._api.available_backends()
    104         for raw_config in configs_list:
    105             try:

ConnectionError: Couldn't connect to IBMQ server: error during login: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You added an "s" in the final.

IBMQ.load_account**s**()

The right way is:

IBMQ.load_account()

I hope I could have helped.